# DB Error on create - Errno 150

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1005

When running the follow query i receive the error below, Im just trying to create this simple table with no FK or anything and still receive this error. What could be the cause?
SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE `xauction`.`orders` (
`id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`type` VARCHAR( 1 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1005 - Can't create table 'xauction.orders' (errno: 150) (Details...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `show innodb status`. Within the big chunk of data it outputs, there's a section that'll have more details than the normal error message you get from the original error-causing query.

Comment: As of MySQL 5.5 you need to use `show engine innodb status` instead.  (As per http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-innodb-status.html)

Answer (score 3):

the syntax is o.k

from [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-error-codes.html) site :

> . If the error message refers to error
>   150, table creation failed because a
>   foreign key constraint was not
>   correctly formed

Comment: That's wierd because i have no FK constraints on this table should I check other tables to make sure everything is ok?

Comment: I wonder how i should proceed with this, is there a way make the FK constraints display ?